# Finding an OMM error while training a ResNet model using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, batchsize

I am Training a ResNet on an **NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 ti** with **4GB**, The image is sized 512x320 using 6 as a batch size which is not really good.

It shows this error:

`(1) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6,128,256,160] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc`

And I was trying to understand tensor parameters, the first(6) one apparently is the number of epochs, the Third and the last (256,160) one is the dimension of the image divided by 2.

I am confused, Is it possible that the GPU is not using the whole memory ?

Comment: You don't have enough memory, reduce your batch size or downscale the architecture of your network.

Comment: How is that ? if the allocation of tensor needs 6x128x256x160x4 Byte!

Comment: The process encountered OOM while trying to allocate a tensor of size `6x128x256x160x4`. It is not the only tensor that was allocated. The first one was one of the size of your input, `6x512x320`, and then following the architecture of your network.

Comment: I see so it is better to use CPU rather than GPU in that case, even though it will take more time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens even if GPU has memory, I don't know the reason but...
Keep reducing batch size, until it does not solve this GPU problem.